# Unexpected result (NaN) when using parenthesis in a Javascript calculation

Tags: javascript, math

I am trying to do a very simple calculation of `11.000 + 5.000` expecting to have  `16.000` then dividing it by `2` expecting to get a final result of `8.000`. It was working ok in another language (ahk) but I'm having unexpected results trying it in javascript (Not a Number, 5.5 and 5.50025)

**How should I write this calculation to get the expected result of 8.000?**

```js
var A = "11.000";
var B = "5.000";

//1st try
var resultA = (A + B) / 2;
alert(resultA);


//2nd try
var resultB = parseInt(A + B) / 2;
alert(resultB);

//3nd try
var resultC = parseFloat(A + B) / 2;
alert(resultC);


//expected = 8.000
```

Comment: what does the dot mean for you? no kidding.

Comment: decimal separator...

Comment: of what? `1 / 10 === 0.1` ? or thousands?

Comment: You're trying to convert `11.0005.000` to int or float - that's why you get a NaN. Do `(parseInt(A)+parseInt(B))/2`

Comment: Here's a debugging tip: When you have a complex expression, break it up into smaller ones so you can debug each step. `var temp = (A+B); var resultA = temp / 2;`

Comment: @NinaScholz these numbers represent results of calculations between svg coordinates like x400 - x200; i'm getting these values from a svg image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `A + B` is doing actually string concationation not simple addition. you need to change them to number first

```js
var A = "11.000";
var B = "5.000";


var resultA = ((+A) + (+B)) / 2;
console.log(resultA);

// You can use toFixed if you three decimal digit

console.log(resultA.toFixed(3));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here A and B are in string format and Once you do A + B the result will be "11.000" + "5.000" = "11.0005.000" (string concatenation). So to get expected result you should parse each string value to Float/Int then do the addition operation.

Try, `var resultD = (parseFloat(A) + parseFloat(B)) /2`

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the quotation marks and the vars will be recognized as number not as string so you'll get the expected result.

```js
var A = 11.000;
var B = 5.000;

//1st try
var resultA = (A + B) / 2;
alert(resultA);


//2nd try
var resultB = parseInt(A + B) / 2;
alert(resultB);

//3nd try
var resultC = parseFloat(A + B) / 2;
alert(resultC);


//expected = 8.000
```